# Is it possible to ignore a hardcoded pdb breakpoint?

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, command-line, pdb

I use `pdb` to debug a Python 2.7 script that includes hardcoded breakpoints using the `pdb.set_trace()` function. When I want to run the script without stopping at the breakpoints I have to comment out all the `pdg.set_trace()` lines, and then when I want to stop at the breakpoints I have to remove the comments which is very inefficient. Is there a way (e.g. a command-line flag) to execute a python script ignoring all the hardcoded breakpoints. For instance, many IDEs like PyCharm have Run Mode which ignores the breakpoints, and Debug Mode which stops at the breakpoints. Can I do something like that from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a feature in pdb.  However you can write the command line option handling into your program and set a global variable such as `DEBUG_MODE = True`  then you just modify all your `pdb.set_trace()` calls to be:

```
if DEBUG_MODE:
    pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution, maybe I can implement a command-line flag with `argparse` that sets `DEBUG_MODE` to True/False so that I don't have to change the global variable manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can set [PYTHONBREAKPOINT](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0553/#environment-variable) global environment variable to turn pdb on or off.

Setting it to 0 will disable pdb and setting it's value to empty value will turn it back on.

Examples:

Disable breakpoint:

```
export PYTHONBREAKPOINT=0
```

Enable breakpoint:

```
export PYTHONBREAKPOINT=
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in code if you find yourself not wanting to exit the current session.

```
import os
os.environ["PYTHONBREAKPOINT"] = "0"
```

Then when you continue your hardcoded breakpoints will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Once the debugging session has been entered, changing the environment variable  `PYTHONBREAKPOINT` won't disable hardcoded `set_trace()` call anymore.

One solution I found, once already in the Python process, is to monkey-patch the set_trace function:

On the pdb prompt:

```
!pdb.set_trace = lambda: None
```

Then press `c` to continue.